# Brain storm on elementary number theory - Undetermined equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ be $n$ positive integers. Let $X \geq 2lcm(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ be another positive integer and $(p_1, p_2, ..., p_n)$ be a non-negative integer solution to the undetermined equation:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_ix_i = X$.

Prove or disprove: There exists $n$ non-negative integers $(q_1, q_2, ..., q_n)$ ($\forall 1 \leq i \leq n$, $0 \leq q_i \leq p_i$) such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n q_ix_i = lcm(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$.

Motivation: This problem comes from a very elementary daily scenario. If you use banknotes with a face value of $2$, $3$, or $5$ to buy food worth $60$, you can certainly buy food worth $30$ without change.

My trial: Use Python to find counterexamples but failed. I also tried to consider the $\max(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n q_ix_i)$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n q_ix_i \leq lcm(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ but this approach doesn't work either. I think this problem might be very easy for smart brains but I am dumb (sad).